# New 450w PSU boots up but no post/signal from the motherboard

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, post

I have a problem reagrding my new 450w that's not functionning correctly, there is no post or any signal from the motherboard. I made sure that other parts are working. here is the config:

```
CPU: Intel Pentium G2030 3.0GHz

RAM: 2 GB DDR3 

No GPU card

Motherboard: Foxcon H61MD-V

PSU: 450w generic brand PSU
```

No hards drives has been plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you attached the 4-pin black-yellow cable (goes in the corner of the MB).

After that, if its not working, remove the RAM module and if everything else is ok it should beep (due to missing RAM). If it doesn't, the MB may be damaged.

Why did you change the PSU initially ?

Comment: The motherboard and RAM are working just fine with a standard PSU. I was selling this 450w PSU to a client that reported it was faulty.

Comment: @user1440382 - Sooooo, the client can't get it to work, you can't get it to work.....probably faulty. :)

Comment: It appears so .